# Weird behaviour when using printf, pipe and fork

Tags: c, pipe, printf, fork

I am learning about how `fork`, `pipe` and `execve` works. I have a main from where i `fork` into a child and parent process. The parent waits until the child has finished writing the output of `ls -la` into `fd[1]` (which is redirected to stdout). The problem is it only works if i have a `printf()` inside of my main right before the parent is called. Otherwise I cannot get an output. You can test it for yourself by uncommenting the line in main. Any idea what is causing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void child_call(int ac, char **ag, char **ep, int fd[2])
{
    char *buf;
    char *argv[3] = {"ls", "-la", NULL};

    dup2(fd[1], 1);
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    execve("/usr/bin/ls", argv, ep);
}

void parent_call(int ac, char **ag, char **ep, int fd[2])
{
    char *buf;

    close(fd[1]);
    while (read(fd[0], buf, 1) > 0)
        write(1, buf, 1);
    close(fd[0]);
}

int main(int ac, char **ag, char **ep)
{
    pid_t   pid;
    int     fd[2];
    int     *status;

    pipe(fd);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
        child_call(ac, ag, ep, fd);
    else
    {
        // printf("uncomment me and it will work\n");
        waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
        parent_call(ac, ag ,ep, fd);
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
}
```

Comment: `waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);` Why do you set `WNOHANG`? That will result in a race condition - will only work if the child completes before `waitpid` is called. That's why adding random unrelated code helps - it puts the parent to sleep and lets the child run. Remove that option or explain why you think it is needed.

Comment: `WNHOHANG` should generally only be used if you're calling `waitpid()` in a loop.

Comment: Actually, in fact you don't need the `waitpid` there at all. The `read` will block. What you should do is keep reading until it gets an `EOF`.

Comment: @kaylum what do you mean by `read` will block? I wanted to use `waitpid` so that it does not read untill everything has been written.

Comment: Why do you have to wait until everything is written? Just read and print as the data comes in. The read will do the wait for you if there is no data yet and will continue when the writer has pushed data into the pipe.